# Undefined array key "name" Laravel 9

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am working with laravel 9. I have table in database named 'products', which have column title where i have product titles. And in my e-commerce website i want to make add to cart. I make it, i have function, which can add, update and remove also product in cart. And i have only 1 problem and i am working on it all over 1 day but nothing comes. When i am going to cart route(which is working), it pops up error Undefined array key "name". My codes are below and please check it guys:

CartController.php

```
                 <?php

   namespace App\Http\Controllers;

        use Illuminate\Http\Request;

      use App\Models\Product;

     class CartController extends Controller
        {
          public function cart()
      {
    return view('cart');
          }

      /**
    * Write code on Method
         *
         * @return response()
       */
          public function addToCart($id)
      {
    $product = Product::findOrFail($id);
      
    $cart = session()->get('cart', []);

    if(isset($cart[$id])) {
        $cart[$id]['quantity']++;
    } else {
        $cart[$id] = [
            "title" => $product->title,
            "quantity" => 1,
            "price" => $product->price,
            "image" => $product->image
        ];
    }
      
    session()->put('cart', $cart);
    return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Product added to cart successfully!');
    }

       /**
      * Write code on Method
       *
     * @return response()
              */
     public function update(Request $request)
       {
        if($request->id && $request->quantity){
         $cart = session()->get('cart');
                 $cart[$request->id]["quantity"] = $request->quantity;
         session()->put('cart', $cart);
            session()->flash('success', 'Cart updated successfully');
         }
         }

      /**
      * Write code on Method
      *
         * @return response()
         */
       public function remove(Request $request)
        {
          if($request->id) {
        $cart = session()->get('cart');
        if(isset($cart[$request->id])) {
            unset($cart[$request->id]);
            session()->put('cart', $cart);
        }
        session()->flash('success', 'Product removed successfully');
         }
       }
         }
```

cart.blade.php

```
                        @extends('layout')

              @section('content')
            <table id="cart" class="table table-hover table-condensed">
             <thead>
              <tr>
        <th style="width:50%">Product</th>
        <th style="width:10%">Price</th>
        <th style="width:8%">Quantity</th>
        <th style="width:22%" class="text-center">Subtotal</th>
        <th style="width:10%"></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
           <tbody>
             @php $total = 0 @endphp
              @if(session('cart'))
              @foreach(session('cart') as $id => $details)
               @php $total += $details['price'] * $details['quantity'] @endphp
            <tr data-id="{{ $id }}">
                <td data-th="Product">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-3 hidden-xs"><img src="{{ $details['image'] }}" 
                   width="100" height="100" class="img-responsive"/></div>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <h4 class="nomargin">{{ $details['name'] }}</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td data-th="Price">${{ $details['price'] }}</td>
                <td data-th="Quantity">
                    <input type="number" value="{{ $details['quantity'] }}" class="form- 
          control quantity update-cart" />
                </td>
                <td data-th="Subtotal" class="text-center">${{ $details['price'] * 
         $details['quantity'] }}</td>
                <td class="actions" data-th="">
                    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove-from-cart"><i class="fa fa- 
    trash-o"></i></button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
               @endif
             </tbody>
            <tfoot>
            <tr>
        <td colspan="5" class="text-right"><h3><strong>Total ${{ $total }}</strong></h3></td>
             </tr>
           <tr>
        <td colspan="5" class="text-right">
            <a href="{{ url('/') }}" class="btn btn-warning"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i> 
           Continue Shopping</a>
            <button class="btn btn-success">Checkout</button>
        </td>
            </tr>
          </tfoot>
         </table>
        @endsection

        @section('scripts')
      <script type="text/javascript">

       $(".update-cart").change(function (e) {
           e.preventDefault();

    var ele = $(this);

       $.ajax({
        url: '{{ route('update.cart') }}',
        method: "patch",
        data: {
            _token: '{{ csrf_token() }}', 
            id: ele.parents("tr").attr("data-id"), 
            quantity: ele.parents("tr").find(".quantity").val()
        },
        success: function (response) {
           window.location.reload();
         }
            });
        });

           $(".remove-from-cart").click(function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();

            var ele = $(this);

             if(confirm("Are you sure want to remove?")) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '{{ route('remove.from.cart') }}',
            method: "DELETE",
            data: {
                _token: '{{ csrf_token() }}', 
                id: ele.parents("tr").attr("data-id")
            },
            success: function (response) {
                window.location.reload();
            }
        });
          }
         });

    </script>
   @endsection
```

shop.blade.php

```
                                                                                                       <div class="container">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-12 main-section" style="background-color: #3D464D !important">
                                    <div class="dropdown">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="dropdown" style="    margin-top: 26px;
                                        margin-left: 54px;
                                        background-color: #FFD333 !important;">
                                            <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i> Cart <span class="badge badge-pill badge-danger">{{ count((array) session('cart')) }}</span>
                                        </button>
                                        <div class="dropdown-menu">
                                            <div class="row total-header-section">
                                                <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-6">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span class="badge badge-pill badge-danger">{{ count((array) session('cart')) }}</span>
                                                </div>
                                                @php $total = 0 @endphp
                                                @foreach((array) session('cart') as $id => $details)
                                                    @php $total += $details['price'] * $details['quantity'] @endphp
                                                @endforeach
                                                <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-6 total-section text-right">
                                                    <p>Total: <span class="text-info">$ {{ $total }}</span></p>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            @if(session('cart'))
                                                @foreach(session('cart') as $id => $details)
                                                    <div class="row cart-detail">
                                                        <div class="col-lg-8 col-sm-8 col-8 cart-detail-product">
                                                            <p>{{ $details['title'] }}</p>
                                                            <span class="price text-info"> ${{ $details['price'] }}</span> <span class="count"> Quantity:{{ $details['quantity'] }}</span>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                @endforeach
                                            @endif
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-12 text-center checkout">
                                                    <a href="{{ route('cart') }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">View all</a>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

please help me!

Comment: May it must be `$details['title']`

Comment: what? please repeat

Comment: i switched but error code is still Undefined array key "name"

Comment: then you have the problem at more places or you have not changed it

Comment: please check and say to me where is it

Comment: You should see it in the error message. Ther should be a file name and a line number

Comment: @Jens actually in my opinion, everywhere i gave title and not name, but i can't solve it, working on it many hours but nothing, please check

Comment: @Jens, in error code, error is in Illuminate
 \ 
Foundation
 \ 
Bootstrap
 \ 
HandleExceptions
 
: 116
handleError

Comment: In the code you shared i see one occurence of name `<h4 class="nomargin">{{ $details['name'] }}</h4>`

Comment: You are working with the changed files?